# Thymeleaf unable to load CSS Styles from template fragments

Tags: css, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am currently working on a To do list application with Spring and Thymeleaf. I have a layout page below which has the sidebar and header elements I plan to use on every page, so I have marked each section with fragments.

**Layouts.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <!-- head element components -->
  <head th:fragment="common-components">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Material+Symbols+Outlined:opsz,wght,FILL,GRAD@20..48,100..700,0..1,-50..200"
    />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/9e3ed6449c.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      th:href="@{/src/main/resources/static/CSS/layouts.css}"
      type="text/css"
    />
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
  </head>

  <body>
    <!-- header section -->
    <div class="header" th:fragment="header">
      <div class="left-section">
        <span class="material-symbols-outlined">menu</span>
        <div>To-do List</div>
      </div>
      <div class="right-section">
        <div class="add-task-container">
          <i class="fa-regular fa-plus fa-xl"></i>
          <div class="tool-tip">Add Task</div>
        </div>

        <!-- Implement later -->
        <div class="daily-goal-tracker-container">0/5</div>

        <!-- Implement later -->
        <div class="user-container">User</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- sidebar section -->
    <div class="sidebar" th:fragment="sidebar">
      <div class="sidebar-link">
        <div>
          <i
            class="fa-solid fa-inbox fa-lg"
            style="color: rgb(22, 127, 162)"
          ></i>
        </div>
        <a class="tab">Inbox </a>
      </div>

      <div class="sidebar-link">
        <i
          class="fa-regular fa-calendar-check fa-lg"
          style="color: rgb(67, 188, 67)"
        ></i>
        <a class="tab">Today</a>
      </div>

      <div class="sidebar-link">
        <i
          class="fa-regular fa-calendar-days fa-lg"
          style="color: rgb(160, 12, 160)"
        ></i>
        <a class="tab">Upcoming</a>
      </div>

      <div class="sidebar-link">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-filter fa-lg" style="color: rgb(226, 149, 5)"></i>
        <a class="tab">Filters and Lables</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

However, when I implement my layouts onto another page, none of the CSS styles I have in place load at all:

**Today.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
  <head th:replace="Layouts :: common-components"></head>

  <body>
    <div th:replace="Layouts :: header"></div>
    <div th:replace="Layouts :: sidebar"></div>

    <!-- The to-do list -->
    <div class="container">
      <form action="/save-task" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="md-form">
            <label for="task">Task Name</label>
            <input placeholder="Enter your task ..." id="task" type="text" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="md-form">
              <label for="task">Due Date</label>
              <input placeholder="" id="task" type="text" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've been stuck on this issue for a couple of days so any help would be greatly appreciated! Below is my pom file for reference too, I've commented out the spring security dependencies and I'm not sure if that may be the cause of the issue or not (relatively a beginner still)

I've already tried using the "/" in the th:href tag like

```
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      th:href="@{/src/main/resources/static/CSS/layouts.css}"
      href="/src/main/resources/static/CSS/layouts.css"
      type="text/css"
    />
```

instead of simply

> th:href="@{src/main/resources/static/CSS/layouts.css}"

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
2.7.5
 

com.personal
todolist-app
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
todolist-app
Demo project for Spring Boot

<java.version>17</java.version>

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity5</artifactId>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency> -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Spring Boot by default looks for static resources in src/main/resources/static among other locations. Try changing your css declaration to th:href="@{/CSS/layouts.css}"

Comment: @LeeGreiner, that solution seemed to work for my layout files so thank you very much, but now that I try to implement general js and css for other functionality I have within this app, neither seem to load and I'm not sure why... I'm using the same declaration

Comment: Bring up developer tools in your browser and 1) see if the resources are actually being requested and 2) post the error and the URL if they are.